# Logarithmic axis not showing appropriate ticks for small numbers

Tags: highcharts

To preface, I am using the extended logarithm functions for negative and small numbers here:

```
/**
* Custom Axis extension to allow emulation of negative values on a 
logarithmic
* Y axis. Note that the scale is not mathematically correct, as a true
* logarithmic axis never reaches or crosses zero.
*/
(function (H) {
    // Pass error messages
    H.Axis.prototype.allowNegativeLog = true;

    // Override conversions
    H.Axis.prototype.log2lin = function (num) {
        var isNegative = num < 0,
            adjustedNum = Math.abs(num),
            result;
        if (adjustedNum < 10) {
            console.log('adjustedNum: ', adjustedNum);
             adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
        }
        result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
     if (adjustedNum < 10) console.log('result: ', result);
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
    };
    H.Axis.prototype.lin2log = function (num) {
        var isNegative = num < 0,
            absNum = Math.abs(num),
            result = Math.pow(10, absNum);
        if (result < 10) {
            result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
        }
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
    };
}(Highcharts));
```

So if I have a y-axis with a dataMin of 0.22 and a dataMax of 2.34 using a log scale, the only ticks I get back are [0,1] designating 0 and 10, the bottom and top of the chart, with no tick marks in between.

1) Is there a way I can specify how many ticks I want in a log chart (tickAmount: 5 would not work)?
2) Is there a way I can tighten the range over which ticks fall? (like in this case, it sets the axis with data values between 0 and 10 even though my data series only falls between 0.22 and 2.34).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to allow for 0 and negative numbers?

Comment: Yep, I have varying time series data that can be zero or negative.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

`tickPositions` and `tickPositioner` options allow you to control where exactly the ticks will fall.

---

**2.**

You can try adjusting the `tickInterval` option: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8v3xuyot/

```
  yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic',
    tickInterval: 0.2
  }
```

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: Yeah seems like that might be the only way to go. I was hoping there'd be a way to get Highcharts to do it correctly for smaller numbers instead of manually setting tickPositions and figuring out the interval. Ok thanks!!